# How solve this Import error when pip list at venv?

Tags: python

- I am using python3.8.8 in windows10. I just typed pip list in
  venv(CMD) which showed a big error. I was using this venv for pip
  installing tensorflow which also showed this similar error

  ```
    ## Heading ## (venv) C:\Users\HP>pip list Traceback (most recent
   call last):   File
   "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py",
   line 194, in _run_module_as_main
       return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py",
   line 87, in _run_code
       exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\HP\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>  
   File "c:\users\hp\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py",
   line 71, in main
       command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))   File
   "c:\users\hp\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py",
   line 96, in create_command
       module = importlib.import_module(module_path)   File "c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py",
   line 127, in import_module
       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import  
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load  
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in
   _find_and_load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen
   importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module   File
   "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
   _call_with_frames_removed   File "c:\users\hp\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\list.py",
   line 5, in <module>
       from pip._internal.cli.req_command import IndexGroupCommand   File
   "c:\users\hp\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py",
   line 16, in <module>
       from pip._internal.index.collector import LinkCollector   File "c:\users\hp\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py",
   line 16, in <module>
       from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests   File "c:\users\hp\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\__init__.py",
   line 25, in <module>
       from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment   File "c:\users\hp\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py",
   line 6, in <module>
       from . import _inputstream   File "c:\users\hp\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_inputstream.py",
   line 10, in <module>
       from pip._vendor import webencodings ImportError: cannot import name 'webencodings' from 'pip._vendor'
   (c:\users\hp\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\__init__.py)
  ```

Comment: Your import seems strange, simply do `import webencodings`

Comment: remove pip ,and install pip3